# How to UV a stretched object?

Tags: uv

I'm a beginner with Blender and I have some problems with understanding how UV works.
I created a box then I changed its dimensions and applied bevel. But when I do the UV (I tried smart UV and others), I get the UV with all of the sides as **squares, not rectangles**.
How can I get the **right proportions of an object**?

[image: UV box]

Comment: Hello :). Noob questions are okay. You need to apply scale first *Object > Apply > Scale*

Comment: .... Apply Scale before beveling.

Comment: Thank you for help! I significantly improved my unwrapping skills :)